# Unable to download from rubygems.org

Tags: ruby

I just installed ruby version 2.3.0p0 using the ruby installer for windows and was trying to install bundler. When I run **gem install bundler** I get the following error:

*Could not find a valid gem 'bundler' (>=0), here is why

Unable to download data from (link removed) rubygems -Errno:ETIMEDOUT:

Failed to open TCP connection to api.rubygems.org:443 (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. -connect(2) for "api.rubygems.org" port 443)([https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)](https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)_)*

Some research led me to try running **gem install --http-proxy http://[user]:[password]@[server]:[port]** which i think might work because I am behind a proxy here and a similiar solution helped me clone a git repository earlier.
But when i tried this command I got the following error:

*ERROR: While executing gem ... (Gem:CommandLineError)

Please Specify at least one gem name (e.g. gem build GEMNAME)*

**UPDATE**
So I tried that *gem install --http-proxy....* command again with the gem name at the end and I am back to getting the original TCP connection error above. I am pretty sure the login  information I entered is correct. I also added **--source http://...** instead of the https one but still am having the same problem?

Comment: My question is why am i getting the second error?

Comment: `Please Specify at least one gem name` Because you did not specify a gem to install. Instead, you must do `gem install --http-proxy http://..... bundler`

Comment: Thanks I just noticed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st off your error is pretty telling-

> ERROR: While executing gem ... (Gem:CommandLineError) Please Specify
>   at least one gem name (e.g. gem build GEMNAME)

2nd make sure you have met the requirements for what you're trying to do http://bundler.io/
then run the code..

```
gem install bundler
bundle init
echo 'gem "rspec"' >> Gemfile
bundle install
bundle exec rspec
```

Answer (score 0):

In 2023, the best way to install bundler on an old version of Ruby is:

```
gem update --system
```

RubyGems and Bundler now ship together, so to get the latest bundler, you should just install the latest RubyGems.

Answer (score -1):

would you try disable ipv6, it had been worked for me